# Subgroups that are isomorphic to each other, and contain a common element are the same subgroup

Tags: group-theory

Consider I have a group $G$ and a automorphism on $G$, $f:G\to G$. 
I have $H\le G$ and $(H)f\le G$ being the image of $H$

As $f$ is automorphism, $(H)f$ is isomorphic to $H$.

But not all subgroups that are Isomorphic to each other are the same subgroup.
Consider $\mathbb{Z_{2\times2}}$ it has 2 subgroups $\langle (10)\rangle$, $\langle (01)\rangle$ for which we can find a isomophism between. But that are different subgroups.

However if we add the additional constraint: $H \cap (H)f\ne{e}$, 
I feel like that should be enough to indicated $H=(H)f=H \cap (H)f$

I'm not so sure where to start with proving his. 
Once I have one element in $H \cap (H)f$ then I have at least the cyclic group generated by that element, but that still doesn't show I have every element.

Comment: Functions applied from the right? E gadd.

Comment: Yeah, function application on the right isn't that unusual for group theory.

Comment: Some group actions are more naturally interpreted as right actions (for example $S_n$ acting on $V^{\otimes n}$, or conjugation $x^\sigma:=\sigma^{-1}x\sigma$ if one wants the "power rule" $(x^\sigma)^\tau=x^{\sigma\tau}$ to hold). Outside of these special cases, I would say right actions are unusual, including in group theory (in particular with functions, and even more specifically, with group automorphisms).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, consider $\mathbb{Z}$ and the subgroups $\langle2\rangle$ and $\langle4\rangle$. These two are clearly isomorphic, yet the first is also clearly a proper subset of the second. To really drive the nail in the coffin, consider $\mathbb{R^3}$ with any two distinct 2-dimensional subspaces (planes). These intersect at a *line*, and are also isomorphic (as are any finite-dimensional vector spaces of the same dimension) and are *not the same subgroup*. The statement is just not correct.

Answer (score 2):

Just because a subgroup intersects nontrivially with its image under an automorphism doesn't mean it's equal to its image. There's simply no reason for it to. Consider $C_2\times C_2\times C_2$ for instance.